# handle existing files with python's eventhandler

Tags: python

In my code, "MyHandler" class inherited from `PatternMatchingEventHandler` takes care of `on_created` and `on_moved` events. For example, if there is a new file created, `on_created` is triggered and calls the `process` function. If the file-name is modified, `on_moved` is triggered and calls the `sending` function BUT currently my class is "blind" to any existing file. Is there a way to make the existing file visible to the class? I looked at documents for some kind of a function like `on_existed` but I did not find anything of that sort.

Comment: `PatternMatchingEventHandler` is for Events, if there are no events then it won't pick them up.  One possibility is to "tickle" each existing file (iterate through the directory) to create an event.  What you use for the tickle depends partly on the OS, and partly on what is safe to change.  You could open the file for read, for example, then immediately close it.

Comment: @cdarke by "tickle" you mean to do something with the file, right? I cannot change the contents of the file. So if I make my code open and close the file, do the event handler class treats it as `on_modified`?